# Combine list query in AngularFire2 5.0.rc2

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm in a `Ionic` App trying to convert a provider with the new release of AngularFire2

I'm totally lost in combining 2 firebase nodes as I use to do before.
I try to retrieve a list of post and each post got a value user, that I want to use to retrieve the user detail and attach it to the post detail.

Here is my current class

```
export class PostProvider {

  public postsRef: AngularFireList<any[]>
  public posts: Observable<any>

  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {

    this.postsRef = this.db.list('/posts')
    this.posts = this.postsRef.snapshotChanges()
      .map(posts => {
        for (let post of posts) {
          return this.db.object(`/users/${post.payload.val().user}`)
            .valueChanges()
            .map(user => {
              console.log(user)
            });
        }
      }).subscribe()
    }
    }
```

What I understood from the AF2 docs is the new `snapshotChanges()` method is the one to use when you need to perform more than retrieving a list.
Any generic example on how to combine this kind of request would be helpful to put me on the right track.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this as I am having the same issue currently where the combine latest does not work.